# array modified in the loop causes bug with the output ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a code that places anagrams into an array of arrays. (which contain anagrams)
but somewhere i made a bug and the first values do not output as arrays but just as strings

I am using the << operator to push one array into the other
the code is not that complicated but i cannot find a bug

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
    indexes = []
    anagrams = []

    words.each{|word| 
    if(word.is_a? String )
        first_word = word.downcase.chars.sort.join
        words.each{|second_word| 
            if(second_word.is_a? String)
                if(first_word == second_word.downcase.chars.sort.join)
                    indexes << words.index(second_word)
                end
            end
        } 

        indexes.each{|index| anagrams << words[index] }
        words.reject!.with_index {|el, idx| indexes.include?(idx)}

        words << anagrams # i replaced words with an array all_anagrams
        indexes = []
        anagrams = []
    end
    }

    return words
end

puts combine_anagrams([ 'cars','for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four','scar', 'creams', 'scream'] ).inspect
```

outputs

```
["for", "four", ["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["potatoes"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

if i switch the order of "cars" and "for" in the input i get

```
["cars", "racs", "scar", ["for"], ["potatoes"], ["four"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

Whats going on here

Sorry for the messy code im just begging to learn ruby

I created an additional variable `all_anagrams = []` to store the array of  all anagrams 
when i output the array onto the sreen i get all the values except the "for" and "four" for some reason those never get send to `all_anagrams`
probably because i shorten the array when i am in the loop and those values get skipped over?
However i dont know how to deal with this problem.

the output of all_anagrams is

```
[["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["potatoes"], ["creams", "scream"]]
```

Comment: Your indentation is absolutely horrible; I can't follow your code.

Comment: sorry let me fix that i am used to eclipse but i dont have eclipse on this because its a virtual drive of ubuntu. I dont know a good program for it that will do indentations :(

Comment: Try the tab key or the space bar. I know we're all lazy but there comes a point where readability eventually trumps laziness.

Comment: yes i did tab key. thank you for leet advice :)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude (and your code looks much better now). "I don't know a good program that will do indentations" was a rather poor excuse for not doing us the courtesy of indenting, and I presume you would like us to be able to follow your code. If you get into the habit of indenting, *especially when learning a new language*, hopefully you can even follow *your own* code too.

Comment: yea you are right. I just forget to do it since I am used to ctr+I doing it for me. I copy pasted my code and forgot to indent it prior of doing so. I know I should have and i will remember from now on.

Comment: You're modifying the words array as you iterate over it - not a good plan. You may be interested in group_by

Comment: As for what's going on now, this is a pretty good question :). I must be missing something too, though I suspect it's something to do with modifying an array as you are iterating through it, which is pretty much *undefined behavior*. You sure you don't want to create a *new* array for the anagrams and return that? It would eliminate the need for `is_a? String` calls too and greatly shorten the number of iterations as the array grows longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is introduce a new array to store anagrams before you blank it, lets call it `valid_anagrams`. Right now you're pushing that in `words`. And as Fredrick pointed out you're modifying words while iterating over it. Its not good and to avoid that you keep a clone of words called `words_clone` and reject items from it instead. Following code should work -

```
def combine_anagrams(words)
    indexes, anagrams, valid_anagrams = [], [], []
    words_clone = words.clone # creating a clone of words

    words.each do |word|
            if(word.is_a? String )
                 first_word = word.downcase.chars.sort.join
                words.each do |second_word|
                        if(second_word.is_a? String)
                            if(first_word == second_word.downcase.chars.sort.join)
                                    indexes << words.index(second_word)
                            end
                        end
                end

                indexes.each{|index| anagrams << words[index] }

                # reject from words_cloned instead of words
                words_clone.reject!.with_index {|el, idx| indexes.include?(idx)}

                # insert anagrams into valid_anagrams array. In your code you inserted it in words array
                valid_anagrams << anagrams unless valid_anagrams.include?(anagrams)
                indexes, anagrams = [], []
            end
    end

    # return valid_anagrams array
    return valid_anagrams
end
```

Comment: it works! awesome! and beautiful indentation may i add :P Im new to ruby so your syntax helps me learn. If you are given an array of strings you dont need the if(second_word.is_a? String) statements. I can take them out now and the code will still work for all cases??